# how to change title without refresh or reload ? It can be changed by jquery but effect will not be done on view source. any solution ?? Thanks

Tags: html

how to change title without refresh or reload ? It can be changed by jquery but effect will not be done on view source.

i've use document.title. On browser it is changing value but when i open page source it shows blank.

Comment: please add the fildde of your code

Answer (score 1):

There is no way to change the *source* of a page with (client-side) JavaScript. The source is the raw code that was delivered to the browser.

You can change the current DOM, and a DOM viewer (such as you can find built into most browser Developer Tools) will show you a serialization of the current state of the DOM.

Comment: Thanks for your reply Quentin. I mean to say that when my page is loaded it contains value in <title>. But after loading complete when i am trying to change the title, it gets change into document of browser but not into the view source. it still displays the old value which was bind at the time of page first load. Definitely it will not help in SEO. CAN YOU SHARE ANY LINK FOR DOM SERIALIZATION EXAMPLE

Comment: **There** still **is no way to change the source of a page with (client-side) JavaScript** (and even if there was, it wouldn't do any good since search engine indexers tend not to execute JavaScript anyway).

Comment: Getting a DOM serialization, as described in the answer, can be achieved by using Chrome, right clicking on the page, then picking "Inspect Element".

Comment: If you want to serve SEO, then build quality content and 
follow the principles of [Progressive Enhancement](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Progressive_enhancement) and [Unobtrusive JavaScript](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Unobtrusive_JavaScript). Don't depend on JS for access to basic content.

Answer (score 0):

> ...but when i open page source it shows blank.

Could you elaborate? I've just tried this myself and it works fine:

```
<head>
    <title>Abc</title>
</head>

$(document).ready(function() {
    $('title').text('test');
})
```

When viewing the source of the page the `title` now contains "test".

[JSFiddle example](http://jsfiddle.net/47yk4/).

Comment: Thanks for your reply james. I mean to say that when my page is loaded it contains value in <title>. But after loading complete when i am trying to change the title, it gets change into document of browser but not into the view source. it still displays the old value which was bind at the time of page first load. Definitely it will not help in SEO.