# Javascript - can't set popup title properly

Tags: javascript, html

I want to be able to change the title and HTML content of a popup window I open in the page at will.
While changing content (via `document.write()`) works fine, the title to some reason does not change after the first time I change the content. Below is a short example code:

```
  var targetDocument = window.open().document;
  targetDocument.title = "A";
  targetDocument.title = "B";
  targetDocument.open("text/html", "replace");
  targetDocument.write("<html>" + 
    "<head><title> C </title></head>" +
    "<body> Hello! </body></html>");
  targetDocument.close();
  targetDocument.title = "D";
  console.log("Title: " + targetDocument.title);
```

After that code, the popup displays "B" as title and, similarly, "B" is logged to console (while D is expected). Am I doing something wrong?

I am using Chrome.

Comment: It displays D on my end. I checked on jsbin. logs D as well.

Comment: Fiddle here seems to work fine... https://jsfiddle.net/0f883xgo/

Comment: D for me as well on Firefox

Comment: I see D, Chrome 42 Mac OS

Comment: Does your code also contain some other popup window's info after these lines of code? if Yes than this could be because of javascript's reference assignment. The later assignments could be overriding the prior targetDocument's data.

Comment: No, there is nothing else in the script. Probably this is something related to installed extensions / my PC / Chrome build, will try to find what happened...

Answer (score 0):

It could be something with the way html pages are loaded. Once open a title can not change unless you refresh it.

See this similar problem - [How to change title](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15243516/how-to-change-title-without-refresh-or-reload-it-can-be-changed-by-jquery-but)

Comment: If your "answer" begins with "I am only commenting..." perhaps leave it as a comment instead of an answer.

Comment: Changed it because I started it as a comment but decided to put it as an answer.